# Caching HTML Pages

Tags: caching, solr, page-caching

I wanted a mechanism to cache/index the html pages for a website as it is.
So, that if a requests comes for that page again, I can simply fetch that page from cache or index and send it.
Is it possible with Solr? Because Solr always seems to store display (text) part of the html and not the entire HTML Dom.
Is there any other open-source technology which can help me do that with fast performance?

Comment: Hmm, I am thinking "caching proxy" here. Where do you want to place this cache? And does your question involve indexing html files for searching?

Answer (score 1):

There's a lot of missing detail in this question, but the answer to your question about Solr in particular is yes, Solr can store raw HTML just fine. Normally you use a field with stored="true" to be able to retrieve the original HTML, and indexed="true" along with a [HTML filter](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/AnalyzersTokenizersTokenFilters#solr.HTMLStripCharFilterFactory) to keep only the text searchable.